# acf the page is unable to handle the request

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have introduced this simple if-else using advanced custom fields to see if the values are being checked but whenever I introduce it in the code the page says its currently unable to handle the request.

```
                        <?php 
                            if(in_array('strategy', get_field('services_provided'))){
                            echo "strategy";
                            }else if(in_array('design', get_field('services_provided'))){
                            echo "design";
                            }else if{in_array('dev ', get_field('services_provided')){
                            echo "dev";
                            }else{
                            echo "error";
                            }

                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were typo's in the code,

```
<?php 
    if(in_array('strategy', get_field('services_provided'))){
        echo "strategy";
    }
    else if(in_array('design', get_field('services_provided'))){
        echo "design";
    }else if(in_array('dev', get_field('services_provided'))){
        echo "dev";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```